# --help for a selected command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

Is it possible to get --help message for a selected argument in command prompt?

Example: 
`python my_program.py -h` in cmd will provide the whole help message.
Say my_program.py takes 2 cmdline argument `-a` and `-b`. Can I get the `--help` message of `-a` alone?

Something like this, `python my_program.py -h -a`. Is that possible?

Comment: You can have specific help for a sub command, but not for a specific argument (without adding custom parsing, as far as I'm aware). Why do you not want the conventional help layout?

Comment: No you can't do this for arguments